# C function for maniplulating string

Tags: c, char, c-strings

I have written this exercise which should remove any chars in the first argument string which appear in the second string. But the result is a segmentation fault for the arguments below. Can any one explain to me what am  I missing?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void squeez(char s1[], char s2[])
{
  int i, j, k, match;
  while (s1[i] != '\0') {
    match = 0;
    for (k = 0; s2[k] != '\0'; ++k) {
      if (s1[i] == s2[k]) {
    match = 1;
    break;
      }
    }
    if (match) {
      i++;
    } else {
      s1[j++] = s1[i++];
    }
  }
  s1[j] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
  char s[] = "asdsffffsffsk";
  char x[] = "sf";
  squeez(s, x);
  printf("%s %s", s, x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: call `strcspn()` in a loop?

Comment: `i`, `j` are not initialized

Comment: A good start would be to initialize `i` to `0`.  As it is, its values is unknown, so who knows where in memory you're trying to index? Similarly for `j`.  No wonder you're getting segmentation faults.

Comment: This seems like the perfect time to learn how to use a *debugger* to catch crashes and locate when and where in your code they happen. When you have caught the crash, you can also examine the values of all involved variables to make sure they are okay (like array indexes being in range).

Comment: `if (s1[i] == s2[k])` ==> `if (s1[i+k] == s2[k])` and additional range check. You also need to `break` from the outer loop, otherwise you'll ignore any match that was not at the end, and in fact revise the logic completely: `match++` must be equal to `strlen(s2)`.

Comment: Using indexes into the array is a lot more complicated than incrementing `s1`.  Get comfortable with pointer arithmetic; it should be your best friend.

Answer (score 2):

For starters the function should be declared the following way

```
char * squeez( char s1[], const char s2[] );
```

That is the second parameter should have the qualifier `const` because the string specified by this parameter is not changed in the function.

The function should follow the general convention of C standard string functions and return pointer to the result string.

Within the function variables `i` and `j` are not initialized and have indeterminate values. So even the first while loop

```
int i, j, k, match;
while (s1[i] != '\0') {
// ...
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Instead of the type `int`  of these variables you should use the type `size_t` because the type `int` can be not large enough to store lengths of strings.

You should declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.

Keeping your approach to the function definition it can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * squeez( char s1[], const char s2[] )
{
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    
    while ( s1[i] != '\0' ) 
    {
        int match = 0;
        
        for ( size_t k = 0; !match && s2[k] != '\0'; ++k ) 
        {
            if ( s1[i] == s2[k] ) match = 1;
        }

        if ( !match ) s1[j++] = s1[i];
        i++;
    }
    
    s1[j] = '\0';
    
    return s1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "asdsffffsffsk";
    char x[] = "sf";
    
    puts( squeez( s, x ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
adk
```

Also as the variable `i` is not used outside the while loop then the while loop could be substituted for a for loop where the variable `i`  will be declared. For example

```
char * squeez( char s1[], const char s2[] )
{
    size_t j = 0;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++ ) 
    {
        int match = 0;
        
        for ( size_t k = 0; !match && s2[k] != '\0'; ++k ) 
        {
            if ( s1[i] == s2[k] ) match = 1;
        }

        if ( !match ) s1[j++] = s1[i];
    }
    
    s1[j] = '\0';
    
    return s1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to me most of your points are C-style questions. It would be great if you comment more on your decisions, e.g. why should the function return a pointer to the s1 arg, even though the function is modifying that string in-place?

Comment: @Student  This convention is adopted for C string functions. For example consider the function strcpy. The function returns pointer to the result string. In this case you can use such a function in expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the i and j are not initialized. In fact, your code is workable without the problem that I put forward. This is the code I tried.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void squeez(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int index1 = 0, position = index1, index2 = 0;
    int match = 0;
    while (s1[index1] != '\0')
    {
        match = 0;
        for (index2 = 0; s2[index2] != '\0'; index2++)
        {
            if (s1[index1] == s2[index2])
            {
                match = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (match)
            index1++;
        else
            s1[position++] = s1[index1++];
    }
    s1[position] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "asdsffffsffsk";
    char x[] = "sf";
    squeez(s, x);
    printf("%s %s", s, x);
    return 0;
}
```